# как подключить файл обработчик (php) контактной формы в wordpress?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="form">
<div id="messegeResult">Оставьте ваши контакты и наш консультант свяжется с вами </div>
<form method="post" action="" id="formMain">
**сама форма:** 
    <input id="telephone" type="Tel" name="telephone" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off"/>
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" />
<input id="button" type="button"  value="Заказать обратный звонок" 
onclick="AjaxFormRequest('messegeResult', 'formMain', 'form.php')"/>               </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax метод**

```
function AjaxFormRequest(result_id,formMain,url) {
           jQuery.ajax({
              url:     url,
              type:     "POST",
              dataType: "html",
              data: jQuery("#"+formMain).serialize(),
              success: function(response) {
                 document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = response;
              },
              error: function(response) {
                 document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = "Возникла ошибка при отправке формы. Попробуйте еще раз";
              }
           });

           jQuery(':input','#formMain')
             .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
             .val('')
             .removeAttr('checked')
             .removeAttr('selected');
        }
```

в браузере получаю ответ  [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 5233мс].

Comment: success или error что-нибудь отдают? попробуйте формировать переменную url так:
url: template_path + '/form.php'

Comment: а файл form.php есть? Если он есть, то есть вариант, что проблема в путях, посмотрите в отладчике, по какому пути отправляется запрос.

Comment: template_path  = bloginfo('template_directory')

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно зарегистрировать обработчики для ajax c помощью WordPress hooks.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action_name', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action_name', 'my_action' );
function my_action() {
  /*тут код обработки данных формы*/
  if(/*все ок*/){
    wp_send_json_success();
  }else{
    wp_send_json_error($error_details);
  }
}
```

Это все добавить в файлик functions.php

+небольшие изменения в js

1) `var url='<?= admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );?>';`

2) и в форму добавить поле `<input type='hidden' name='action' value='my_action_name'>`